# Animate a Reanimated Animated.View from zero width to flex fill smoothly

Tags: react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated

I have a `react-native-reanimated` View that is zero width when `flex: 0` and fills available width when `flex: 1`.

I want to animate the transition smoothly, making the view animate from 0 width to fill availabla width dynamically, while also animating any elements as it grows:

```
[#1 first elem] -- [#2 elem i want to grow] -- [#3 elem that should be pushed animated because #2 grows animated]
```

In my initial view, as #2 has zero width, it looks like `[#1] -- [#3]`. I want to animate `flex` of #2 from `0` to `1`, but it animates immediately to full width instead of smoothly animating. I can imagine why this happens (as flex is relative, there is no difference between non-zero values as long as it's the only flex-filling element) but don't know how to solve it.

Given that:

- The full width of my animating element is dynamic
- The elements after the animating element also need to be pushed *animated* in the layout

How can I animate a Reanimated View to grow in size and animatedly push any elements after it in the layout?

I'm using Reanimated 3.4.1.

Comment: You'll probably have to calculate the target width in pixels before you start the animation.

Comment: Create a View with flex: 1 and inside of it create the Animated.View that will go from 0 to 100% width, that should work

Comment: @bbernag If I create a flex view outside, how can I animate pushing adjacent elements? I get the animate width from 0% to 100% part but the adjacent elements will stay pushed regardless, which I can't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up measuring container view, first element (the one before the animated/growing), last element (the one after the animated/growing) on layout, calculated available space (container - first element's width - last element's width - any paddings etc) and animated the width of the element to that value.